# Music & Sound With C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**Problem:**
I need music that repeats/loops in the background while I am running my program. Then, when I get to another part of my program, that background music needs to pause, play another sound file, then resume the background music.

**Example Of Problem:**
For example, I have a Blackjack program that plays the background music when you run it. Then, when you actually log in or create an account it plays a sound file that says "Welcome". Or if i get to a function that shuffles my vector(deck of cards), it plays a sound effect that sounds like a deck of cards shuffling.

**What I Have Tried:**

- Playsound() - It loops/repeats but does not allow me to pause, resume, etc. My code is:

  ```
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <mmsystem.h>
  #pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib") // Link to the winmm library

  PlaySound(TEXT("86876__milton__title-screen.wav"), NULL, SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC); // Background music
  ```
- MCI - Can't figure out how to get it to loop/repeat, pause, or resume. All I can get is the following code:

  ```
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <mmsystem.h>
  #pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib") // Link to the winmm library

  MCIERROR me = mciSendString("open 86876__milton__title-screen.wav type waveaudio alias song1",NULL, 0, 0);
  if (me == 0)
  {
      me = mciSendString("play song1", NULL, 0, 0);
  }
  ```
- I keep reading that I need to stay away from 3rd party stuff when working with Visual Studio, or anything Microsoft. But, if you can suggest something that is nice and easy, then please.

**Other:**
I am a beginner so I need it to be as simple as possible. For Python Pygame mixer, it is literally 1 line to play, pause, resume etc. I need something like that!

Comment: Well pygame is a framework and naturally the Windows API might not have functions quite as high-level. Maybe try a framework like SFML if you want higher levels of abstraction.

Comment: Does anyone think it would cause some kind of problem down the road if I use Playsound and MCI together? For example, playsound has my looping background music and MCI will do the quick sound effect tidbits that occur throughout the game..??